# File.dirname returns wrong path in ruby 2.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When installing rspec on Rails 4.2.0/ruby 2.2.3 platform, it generates an error:

```
$ rails g rspec:install
   identical  .rspec
       exist  spec
      create  spec/C:/Users/Jun C/AppData/Local/Temp/d20160221-13928-5s67uj/spec/spec_helper.rb
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `mkdir': Invalid argument @ dir_s_mkdir - C:/D/code/rails_proj/engines/simple_projectx/spec/C: (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `fu_mkdir'
```

The problem is with the line:

```
create  spec/C:/Users/Jun C/AppData/Local/Temp/d20160221-13928-5s67uj/spec/spec_helper.rb
```

Here the `spec/C:/Users/Jun C/AppData/Local/Temp/d20160221-13928-5s67uj` should point to the spec subdirectory under Rails app root which is `C:/d/code/rails_proj/engines/simple_projectx/`. The correct path should be:

```
create  C:/d/code/rails_proj/engines/simple_projectx/spec/spec_helper.rb
```

Here is the portion of `ruby` `fileutils.rb`:

```
def mkdir_p(list, options = {})
    fu_check_options options, OPT_TABLE['mkdir_p']
    list = fu_list(list)
    fu_output_message "mkdir -p #{options[:mode] ? ('-m %03o ' % options[:mode]) : ''}#{list.join ' '}" if options[:verbose]
    return *list if options[:noop]

    list.map {|path| remove_tailing_slash(path)}.each do |path|
      # optimize for the most common case
      begin
        fu_mkdir path, options[:mode]
        next
      rescue SystemCallError
        next if File.directory?(path)
      end

      stack = []
      until path == stack.last   # dirname("/")=="/", dirname("C:/")=="C:/"
        stack.push path
        path = File.dirname(path)
      end
      stack.reverse_each do |dir|
        begin
          fu_mkdir dir, options[:mode]
        rescue SystemCallError
          raise unless File.directory?(dir)
        end
      end
    end

    return *list
  end
  module_function :mkdir_p

  alias mkpath    mkdir_p
  alias makedirs  mkdir_p
  module_function :mkpath
  module_function :makedirs

  OPT_TABLE['mkdir_p']  =
  OPT_TABLE['mkpath']   =
  OPT_TABLE['makedirs'] = [:mode, :noop, :verbose]

  def fu_mkdir(path, mode)   #:nodoc:
    path = remove_tailing_slash(path)
    if mode
      Dir.mkdir path, mode
      File.chmod mode, path
    else
      Dir.mkdir path   #line #252 which causes error
    end
  end
   .....................
```

`Dir.mkdir path` is the line causing the error. How to make `ruby` to submit a correct `path`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get support from official RSpec repository: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.